# Rails 4 ShopifyAPI: How to order/sort a query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, ruby-on-rails-4, shopify

I am querying the Shopify dev store database, and it returns the items fine, but the 'order' parameter does not seem to work (the 'limit' parameter does)...

home_controller.rb

```
if params[:search]
  # get 10 products via search parameter and order by title ascending
  @info['products'] = ShopifyAPI::Product.where(title: params[:search], :params => {:limit => 10, :order => "title ASC"})
else
  # get 10 products and order by created_at descending
  @info['products'] = ShopifyAPI::Product.find(:all, :params => {:limit => 10, :order => "created_at DESC"})
end
```

I have tried 'ASC' and 'DESC'. Do you know where I am going wrong?

Comment: Is it likely that the ShopifyAPI does not fully understand the queries from Rails 4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to use `ActiveRecord` query syntax on an `ActiveResource` model (the `shopify_api` gem uses `ActiveResource`). `ActiveResource` has it's own query syntax, although it's similar to the `ActiveRecord` query syntax.

`ActiveResource` doesn't have an `order` method. The [ActiveResource::Base](http://rdoc.info/github/rails/activeresource/frames) documentation contains a list of available methods and also provides some working examples.

Sometimes the API you're consuming provides a method to sort the results. But the Shopify API doesn't provide those methods.

So you should sort the results locally, for example using `sort_by` ([see ruby-doc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by)).

Comment: Ace! Thank you, I had not realised the difference. That is so helpful!